# How to watch certain class variables for changes and execute code when conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm writing a javascript class called Player and want there to be some code that gets executed when a Player object's health variable drops below 0, like writes a message saying Player  has died! I am not sure how to effectively use setters to accomplish this but I am open to other solutions that would get the job done. I have attached an example code of what I am working with and I would appreciate solutions or any tips to improve technique when writing/working with js classes.

```
 class Player {
  constructor(name, health, mana, attack, defense) {  
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defense = defense;
  }

  attackPlayer(secondPlayer) {
    secondPlayer.health = secondPlayer.health - this.attack;
    console.log(this.name + " attacks " + secondPlayer.name + " pwnishungly and deals " + this.attack + " in damage." );  
  }
}


var AK = new Player("AK", 100, 200, 60, 100, 2);
var Joe = new Player("Joe", 100, 250, 85, 60, 2);

Joe.attackPlayer(AK);
```

Comment: You could use the `set` method in ES6
Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Player {
  private _health: number
  constructor(name, health, mana, attack, defense) {  
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defense = defense;
  }

  get health(){
   return this._health;
  }
  
  set health(value){
    if(value===0) {
      console.log('Player has died!');
    }
    this._health = value;
  }
  
  attackPlayer(secondPlayer) {
    secondPlayer.health = secondPlayer.health - this.attack;
    console.log(this.name + " attacks " + secondPlayer.name + " pwnishungly and deals " + this.attack + " in damage." );  
  }
}
```